# Ball falling towards earth

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, momentum

When a ball is dropped towards earth, do we assume the earth to be stationary so that when the ball rebounds, the earth experience a change in momentum upwards, or do we say that when the ball is dropped, the earth starts accelerating towards the ball as well as the ball accelerating towards the earth, and when the ball rebounds, the earth experiences a change in momentum downward equal in magnitude to that of the ball?

Comment: Look at a calculation for an elastic collision. You will see that almost no momentum is transferred, if one mass is significantly bigger than the other.

Answer (score 1):

Earth is always stationary in cases like these.

The ball accelerates towards the earth, and not vice-versa. This is because of the very small mass of the ball when compared to the Earth.

Though theoretically for conservation of linear momentum, the earth should also gain some momentum, but that is again very very negligible due to the huge mass of the latter.

We always say that the Earth exerts Gravitational force on us, and not vice-versa, although by theory both are correct. The reason is same for this also.

The earth does not remain stationary when we view things from an astronomical point of view, which is not the case here.